# Do disconnected complex lie groups exist?

Tags: lie-groups, complex-manifolds

Is it possible for a complex Lie group to be disconnected? What about a compact complex Lie group?

Comment: Are there disconnected complex lie groups that are NOT finite groups? (p.s. any finite group as a complex Lie group (zero-dimensional one) is not so illuminating to me as a great example.)

Comment: @anniemariecœur Yes. Take the direct product of any Lie group with any finite group.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, every finite group is a complex Lie group (zero-dimensional one).

Edit. Incidentally, [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_Lie_group) is unaware of existence of nontrivial finite groups as it erroneously claims that every compact complex Lie group is a complex torus. The correct statement is 
that every **connected** compact complex Lie group is a complex torus. A proof can be found for instance   [here](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/vigregroup/vigre04/abvaran.pdf). The general statement is that for every compact complex Lie group $G$ there exists a short exact sequence
$$
1\to A \to G\to F\to 1
$$
where $A$ is abelian (a complex torus, the connected component of the identity in $G$) and $F$ is a finite group. Such sequence may or may not split.

Conversely, given a sequence as above, where $A$ is a complex torus and $F$ is a finite group whose action on $A$ is holomorphic, $G$ has natural structure of a compact complex Lie group. Such group is disconnected if (but not only if) $F$ is nontrivial and the sequence splits.

Comment: And compact, to boot! :-)

Comment: More generally, the direct product of an $n$-dimensional complex Lie group and a nontrivial finite group is a disconnected $n$-dimensional complex Lie group.

Comment: Are there disconnected complex lie groups that are NOT finite groups?

Comment: p.s. any finite group as a complex Lie group (zero-dimensional one) is not so illuminating to me as a great example.

Comment: @anniemariecœur Of course, just take the direct product of a connected one and a finite one.

Comment: Is it possible to have something more like semidirect product? nontrivial action between the twos?

Comment: Dear @anniemariecœur, Yes, semidirect product you described exists, see Ch. III, sec 1, no.5, Proposition 7 of Groupes et Algèbres de Lie by Bourbaki.